# Issues with tar command

Tags: bash, tar

I'm trying to figure out why is the following tar command not working -

I've tried the following 2 versions &  both don't work -

**Version 1**

```
tar -c --use-compress-program=pigz -f /home/jhonst/data_lake/1m/UX.tar -C '/home/jhonst/data_lake/1m/*.UX.csv'
```

The error I see is

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

**Version 2**

```
tar -c --use-compress-program=pigz -f /home/jhonst/data_lake/1m/UX.tar -C '/home/jhonst/data_lake/1m/*.UX.csv' .
```

The error I see is

```
    tar: 
/home/jhonst/data_lake/1m/*.UX.csv: Cannot open: No such file or directory
    tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Please could someone guide me on what I am doing wrong

Comment: The `-C` flag looks out of place there - have you read `man tar` and confirmed that it needs to be there?

Comment: The argument to `-C` needs to be a directory to change to, not a wildcard pattern for files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```sh
tar -c --use-compress-program=pigz -f /home/jhonst/data_lake/1m/UX.tar /home/jhonst/data_lake/1m/*.UX.csv
```

You'll get:

```sh
tar -t -f /home/jhonst/data_lake/1m/UX.tar
home/jhonst/data_lake/1m/file1.UX.csv
home/jhonst/data_lake/1m/file2.UX.csv
...
```

Which is not the best. There are two possibilities for getting rid of the "path" inside the tar archive:

- Go inside the directory with `cd` (in a subshell or with `pushd`/`popd` if you want to return to the original directory after the tar command):

```sh
cd /home/jhonst/data_lake/1m && tar -c --use-compress-program=pigz -f UX.tar *.csv
```

```sh
# returning to the same place after the tar:
(cd /home/jhonst/data_lake/1m && tar -c --use-compress-program=pigz -f UX.tar *.csv)
# or:
pushd /home/jhonst/data_lake/1m && {
    tar -c --use-compress-program=pigz -f UX.tar *.csv
    popd
}
```

- Use the `-C` option of GNU tar, which is not that easy to handle:

```sh
dirpath=/home/jhonst/data_lake/1m
files=("$dirpath"/*.csv)
tar -c --use-compress-program=pigz -f "$dirpath"/UX.tar -C "$dirpath" "${files[@]#$dirpath/}"
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. This works. Great stuff. I chose option 2 as I have to tar thousands of directories & run the job in background